# How do you get the value of a radio button in Android?

Tags: android

I've searched for the answer to similar questions and can't find the answer.

I can't seem to call `subwayMcDClick` from my Java code. I don't know what to put in the parentheses `(View view)`. Here is my code:

```
   public void submitAnswer(View view) {

    // 1) Which has the most calories? Subway vs. McD's
    subwayMcDClick();

    // 4) Which two have the most caffeine?
    CheckBox brewedCoffeeCheckbox = findViewById(R.id.brewed_coffee_checkbox);
    boolean brewedCoffeeCaffeine = brewedCoffeeCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox brewedBlackTeaCheckbox = findViewById(R.id.brewed_black_tea_checkbox);
    boolean brewedBlackTea = brewedBlackTeaCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox colaCheckbox = findViewById(R.id.cola_checkbox);
    boolean cola = colaCheckbox.isChecked();

    CheckBox rootBeerCheckbox = findViewById(R.id.root_beer_checkbox);
    boolean rootBeer = rootBeerCheckbox.isChecked();

    if (brewedCoffeeCaffeine && brewedBlackTea) {
        caffeine_4 = true;
    } else caffeine_4 = false;

    String answerMessage = createAnswerSummary(caffeine_4);
    displayMessage(answerMessage);

}

public void subwayMcDClick(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.subway_vegetarian_button:
            if (checked)
                calories_1 = true;
        case R.id.mcd_big_mac_button:
            if (checked)
                calories_1 = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `subwayMcDClick(view);` ?

Comment: What is calling `submitAnswer `?

Comment: please share your UI screen. Are you looking for many radio buttons or check boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a RadioGroup in your XML layout like this

```
<RadioGroup
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="90dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
      android:weightSum="1"
      android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3">

      <RadioButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="55dp"
         android:text="SUBWAY_VEGETARIAN"
         android:id="@+id/radioButton"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:checked="false"
         android:textSize="25dp" />

      <RadioButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="McDonalds"
         android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:checked="false"
         android:textSize="25dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.13" />
   </RadioGroup>
```

then, in your Activity use it like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      private RadioGroup radioGroup;
      private RadioButton radioButton;
      private Button submit;

 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

      //i assume you have a submit button
      submit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
      submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            int selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if(selectedId==R.id.radioButton){
               //do something when subway is selected
            }
            else if(selectedId==R.id.radioButton2){
               //do something when McD is selected
            }
         }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to know. @davidtspf. Kindly mark my solution as answer, so others know about it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

just send the checkbox as a parameter, 
Assume that 'cb' is the checkbox you want to get the value of

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
subwayMcDClick(cb);
```